# Shortest way to call a function without using its argument label?

Tags: swift, arguments, label

This question is just having fun with Swift.  Please don't take it too seriously...

In Swift, given this function:

```
func greet(name: String) {
    print("Hello \(name)!")
}
```

the proper way of calling it is like this:

```
greet(name: "Bob")  // "Hello Bob!"
```

If you omit the *argument label* `name`:

```
greet("Bob")
```

you get the error: **Missing argument label 'name:' in call**

But treating the function as a *closure* allows you to call it without the argument label:

```
let g = greet; g("Bob")  // "Hello Bob!"
```

This made me wonder, what is the most concise way of calling a function without using its argument label?

---

**Wrap it in a tuple?**

I thought wrapping the function in a *tuple* and then extracting it would work:

```
(greet).0("Bob")
```

but this resulted in the error: **Value of type '(String) -> ()' has no member '0'**.

This works:

```
(greet,greet).0("Bob")  // "Hello Bob!"
```

So apparently, Swift treats simple tuples of 1 value as just the value itself.

Giving the tuple argument a label works:

```
(g:greet).g("Bob")  // "Hello Bob!"
(g:greet).0("Bob")  // "Hello Bob!"
```

---

**Put it in an array?**

So far, the most concise way I have found is to put the function into an array:

```
[greet][0]("Bob")  // "Hello Bob!"
```

This uses only 5 characters more than `greet("Bob")` which would seem to be the shortest possible call *if it worked*.

Is there any shorter way to call the `greet(name:)` function without using the argument label than this?

Comment: Are you trying to start an Obfuscated Swift contest?

Comment: One more kidding from my side: write your function like this: func greet(_ name: String)....

Comment: Enjoyed reading your post

Comment: @rmaddy, who, me? ;-). Swift will never come close to Obfuscated C.